# Should Nonces Be Used During Log-In?

Tags: security, authentication, hash, nonce

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) presents the following example of nonce-based authentication:

1. Client requests nonce from server.
2. Server responds with nonce (i.e., hereafter referred to as "server
   nonce").
3. Client uses server nonce, its own client nonce, and user-inputted
   password to generate a hash.
4. Client sends user-inputted username, client nonce, and hash to
   server.
5. Server retrieves both server nonce and user password from its
   database, presumably via username.
6. Server combines server nonce, client nonce and password to
   generate a hash.
7. Server compares hash just generated with hash sent from client.
8. If the hashes match, client is authenticated.  If not, client is
   rejected.

Doesn't this imply that the server stores user passwords in plain text?  In gross violation of security principles that recommend saving salted hashes of passwords rather than the actual passwords themselves?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This protocol is basically a [challenge–response authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication). It is used to avoid sending the actual secret (e. g., password), but the response can only be valid with knowledge of the secret. And to avoid replay attacks, a nonce is incorporated.

However, the mentioned protocol requires the server to store the secret in a retrievable form (e. g., plaintext or encrypted).

But you could change the protocol to allow the use of password hashes instead of the plaintext passwords by requiring the client to generate the same password hash:

1. Client requests *salt* and nonce for user-inputted *username* from server.
2. Server retrieves *salt* from its database, presumably via *username*, and responds with *salt* and nonce (i.e., hereafter referred to as *server nonce*).
3. Client uses *salt* and user-inputted *password* to generate a *password hash* and uses the *password hash*, the *server nonce*, and its own *client nonce* to generate a *nonce hash*.
4. Client sends user-inputted *username*, *client nonce*, and *nonce hash* to server.
5. Server retrieves both *server nonce* and user *password hash* from its database, presumably via *username*.
6. Server combines *server nonce*, *client nonce* and *password hash* to generate a *nonce hash*.
7. Server compares *nonce hash* just generated with *nonce hash* sent from client.
8. If the hashes match, client is authenticated. If not, client is rejected.

Comment: Nice.  I thought of the client hashing on its own, but then was concerned about sending the hashed password (i.e., the value in the server database) across the wire.  Your technique solves that problem.

Comment: Very good explanation but a quick note: I wouldn't recommend the client sending the `server nonce` back. That will allow a man-in-the-middle attack since he could just replace the nonce whereas if the server stores it until the client responds the nonce cannot be modified in the server side, now if it was modified during communication the nonce hashes wouldn't match (since the nonce will be different on the client and server).

Comment: @Gumbo This method has the problem that the server is not doing any further hashing to the `passhash`, so anybody with access to the database could use the stored `passhash` to generate the `nonce hash` and successfully login. Just following the legit login process, but using the retrieved `passwordhash` instead of generating it from user input. This is why only `client-side hashing` is not considered secured. If you could add also `server-side hashing` this method would be almost perfect.

Comment: The problem to adding `server-side hashing` to this algorithm, is that you have to send both, the `passhash` and the `nonce hash`, so the server is able to hash the `passhash` with a `server salt` and compare it with the stored `server-salted-hashed-passhash`. The `noncehash` would be used solely to prevent reply attacks, not for the actual login process. And if you have access to SSL (like HTTPS), this is already covered, rendering the `nonces` useless in this approach.

Comment: I don't think we need the nonce anymore while using HTTPs ((source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36972483/2469583)), unless you want to prevent a legitimate user from doing the request multiple times (idempotency)

Comment: This approach carries the implicit acknowledgement that a user with a particular username exists on the server before authenticating. This means that an attacker could use your standard login interface to very quickly learn which users exist in your system, and very quickly build a targeted dataset of known legitimate users, which would have the opposite of the desired effect.