# Preventing replay REST url's replay attack

Tags: rest, url, authentication, spring-security, https

I've spring security custom rest filter which authenticate client request using the below logic.

**Header Fields**

1. Date in header
2. hmac hashed signature

**Body**

1. hmac encrypted data

iOS client makes this request using POST and I have the expiration
 time set to 15 seconds in server.

Now the question is, If anyone use debugging tools like Charles or
 something else and if he happens to put the breakpoints in url and
 fire the same with in 15 seconds, the nonce will be valid and server
 process the request for the second time. How can I prevent this from
 happening. In this case, nonce is not going to work.

Whatever be the approach, if the hacker gets the final url that is
 about to be fired, it could be possible that he could fire it multiple
 times before the nonce expires......

How can I prevent this from happening?

Could anyone help me finding the best spring security implementation for this?

> Also, is HTTPS by default protects us from replay attack ? Do we need
>   ssl client side validation ( having der format certificate in build
>   and validate this with server certificate ) to make replay attack work with https
>   ? or is it available in https by default ?
>
> In other words,  I am using AFNetworking, Do we need to use SSL
>   Pinning to make use of https replay attack ? or will it work without
>   ssl pinning?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use HTTPS to call your REST API, then [the protocol protects you from replay attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20105/are-ssl-encrypted-requests-vulnerable-to-replay-attacks) at the network level. This means that someone cannot record some encrypted traffic and replay it successfully.

But if you are looking for a way to prevent legitimate clients from issuing the same request multiple times, you will either need to make those request [idempotent](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html) or implement a replay mechanism in your business logic. You could do this by using a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). A nonce does not expire, but can only be used in a single transaction.

Comment: I am using https and iOS AFNetworking SDK to fire requests. Nginx server is configured to accept only HTTPS connection. But merely changing http to https, in client, doesn't provide network security right ? Client has to have handshake / ssl validation to provide ssl encryption that in turn provide security right ?. Because I am facing problem, hackers are using CHARLES debugger and keep firing the duplicate requests. Earlier I had hmac ecryption in header and body wasn't encrypted.  Now I've added AES encryption for body, hmac encryption in header and generated nonce using timestap.

Comment: that expires in 120 secs. Only thing what's not clear to me is that, merely changing http to https provide security ( or) do I need client ssl validation using SSL Pinning option of AFNetworking?.

Comment: MvdD, you mentioned that nonce ( number used only once ) doesn't expire. nonce itself generated by setting a timestamp a head of certain secs/minutes or even hours. So if I get the final url, and if I fire it before nonce expires, I could play replay attack right ( excluding https here ) ?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Look here for generating a nonce: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/106880

Comment: I couldn't find a working example for spring security nonce generation in server side and how to handle nonce url from client side. It would be very helpful if I could get a working example.

Comment: I am looking for the best possible nonce generation for spring security. My primary focus is eliminating replay attack. is there any example for both server and client side example for this particular implementation?

Comment: Moreover, is it true that HTTPS by default protects from replay attack ?. Do we need SSL client side validation( having der certificate in client side and validate this with server certificate) to make this work or is it available by default ?

Comment: I'm not a Java developer, so I can't help you with Spring implementation issues. See the first link in my answer for your last question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...as you said in your first reply, stating that replay is not possible with https, how could someone sending replay attacks to my domain which has only https connection possible. even if someone tries http, inam redirecting to https. I read the link posted in first reply. but thing is not convincing.   so it seems that handshake is necessary to avoid replay attack ????